# split dataframe column including list of lists on multiple rows into pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [[[3,0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 5],[2, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 2],[1, 0.5, 1, 1, 2]], 'b'],
    [[[1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.01, 1],[2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 3],[1, 0.8, 1.0, 0.04, 3]], 'd']],
    index = ['row1', 'row2'],
    columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

I would like to split col1, including list of lists, on multiple lines as follows:

```
        col1                    col2
row1    [3,0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 5]    b
row1    [2, 0.5, 1, 0.8, 2]     b
row1    [1, 0.5, 1, 1, 2]       b
row2    [1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.01, 1]  d
row2    [2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 3]   d
row2    [1, 0.8, 1.0, 0.04, 3]  d
```

and next split col1 in 2 columns, retaining only the second and the third elements

```
        new_col1  new_col2  col2
row1    0.5       0.4       b
row1    0.5       1         b
row1    0.5       1         b
row2    0.5       0.6       d
row2    0.5       0.3       d
row2    0.8       1.0       d
```

How it can be done make using pandas?

Comment: your `df` definition does not produce what you output

Answer (score 0):

For the first step there may not be anything better than a loop:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.index:
    col = df.ix[row, 'col1']
    N = len(col)
    df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame(
        [[c, df.ix[row, 'col2']] for c in col],
        index=[row] * N,
        columns = ['col1', 'col2']))
```

For the second step, just add the new columns and delete the original one:

```
df3 = df2.copy()
df3['new_col1'] = [c[1] for c in df3['col1']]
df3['new_col2'] = [c[2] for c in df3['col1']]
del df3['col1']
```